# Enter only numbers and "-" in textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JQuery syntax to allow users enter only numbers in the text field.  [Live code](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/HkEuf/1/)

Then I need to write an extra code to allow users can enter "-" (hyphen) in the text box, but it doesn't work. [Live code](http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/HkEuf/2666/)

Please help.

HTML

```
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

CSS

```
#errmsg{color: red;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && e.which !=='-' && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow hyphens by adding `String.fromCharCode(e.which) != '-'` (charCode for `-`) into your condition:

```
if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && String.fromCharCode(e.which) != '-' && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    ...
}
```

Demo (updated): http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/2669/

Comment: Wow, it is amazing! how comes 45 is a hyphen? Thank you!

Comment: Every character (printable or not) has a character code - You can easily print it out to the console using `console.log(e.which)`. Test across different browsers and platforms as they need not return the same code uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

**Using regExps is really, really easier!** 
Use the regExp `/[0-9\-]/g` to check if the text contains only the characters you want, and if it doesn't show the error msg.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
        var text = this.value;
        if (text.match(/[0-9\-]/g).join('') != text) {
            $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
        }
    });
});
```